# curl works on command line, not in PHP

Tags: php, php-curl

I'm running Drupal 8 on a Fedora R 28 running Apache/2.4.39 with PHP 7.2.18.
My php curl function is failing, but the command line test works fine.

curl shows up in phpinfo(), is defined in 20-curl.ini, and doesn't show any errors in any of the log files.
I've tried two different SSL certs. 
Testing comes back with flying colors.

Protocols
TLS 1.3 No
TLS 1.2 Yes
TLS 1.1 Yes
TLS 1.0 Yes
SSL 3   No
SSL 2   No

All I get back is:
cURL error (7):
 Couldn't connect to server

```
echo 'Curl: ', function_exists('curl_version') ? 'Enabled' : 'Disabled'
```

returns Enabled.

```
array(26) {
  ["url"]=>
  string(23) "http://www.example.com/"
  ["content_type"]=>
  NULL
  ["http_code"]=>
  int(0)
  ["header_size"]=>
  int(0)
  ["request_size"]=>
  int(0)
  ["filetime"]=>
  int(-1)
  ["ssl_verify_result"]=>
  int(0)
  ["redirect_count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["total_time"]=>
  float(0.000437)
  ["namelookup_time"]=>
  float(0.004549)
  ["connect_time"]=>
  float(0)
  ["pretransfer_time"]=>
  float(0)
  ["size_upload"]=>
  float(0)
  ["size_download"]=>
  float(0)
  ["speed_download"]=>
  float(0)
  ["speed_upload"]=>
  float(0)
  ["download_content_length"]=>
  float(-1)
  ["upload_content_length"]=>
  float(-1)
  ["starttransfer_time"]=>
  float(0)
  ["redirect_time"]=>
  float(0)
  ["redirect_url"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["primary_ip"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["certinfo"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["primary_port"]=>
  int(0)
  ["local_ip"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["local_port"]=>
  int(0)
}
cURL error (7):
 Couldn't connect to server
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I needed to enable outbound connections. Not sure why it wasn't needed for the command line calls. It was probably unset when I rebooted the server.

setsebool httpd_can_network_connect true

[For more info:](https://medium.com/@ismailyenigul/curl-error-7-failed-to-connect-to-and-selinux-1cf3a182d922)